# Ways of handling exceptions

Tags: java

Ok, so I had this question in today's quiz. I wonder what the answer is:

**Which of the following is a valid way of dealing with exceptions:**

```
a. Try and catch blocks
b. include throws in the function header
c. Do nothing assuming that it's a `RunTimeException` or a subclass of it.
d. a & b
e. a, b & c
```

I was confused between d and e. I mean, option c is ambiguous. What do you think is the answer?

I mean, if it's `RunTimeException`, then it's an unchecked exception and we need not necessarily deal with it.

Comment: The correct option is d

Comment: it is a poorly worded question and `c` is indeed ambiguous

Comment: Sweet as. I too went with d but almost went for e.

Comment: `d` would be my choice, a `RunTimeException` is an unchecked exception, meaning that it doesn't require you to catch it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: So, your statement about `RunTimeException` is agreement with option-c, so, shouldn't your answer be e?

Comment: @Shashank: Gosh darn it. :(

Comment: @User2k14 That would make `d` and `e` the same thing.  `d` is more decisive as you should not be attempting to trap unchecked exceptions anyway.  I prefer `d` as the safer option.  This is where the ambiguity sinks in

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Fair enough. I hope my instructor feels the same. :)

Comment: correct option is d. Option c says do nothing assuming it is a runtimeexception. We cannot assume.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is `e`. RunTimeExceptions are unchecked exceptions, that means you do not need to handle them. Therefore `c` is a valid way of handling RunTimeExceptions, because `c` talks about doing nothing. You *can* handle them, but you don't *have* to, so `c` is still valid.

Comment: I agree, but words like `Do nothing` and `assuming` are pretty leading words I think.

Comment: But @ScaryWombat would probably still pick E.

Comment: My feeling is `Do nothing assuming` is never `valid way of dealing` with anything

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think the argument is centered around what is meant by "valid". Since this is probably a Java language course, I'm guessing valid means the compiler won't complain and the language supports it as an option. I think your definition of "valid" is in terms of best programming practices, in which case, yes, if I were to predict a RunTimeException, I would indeed handle it, as it would be smart to in many cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback guys. I just mailed my instructor asking him the answer. I'll share it with you when I get to know it. :)

Comment: @Shashank has made a good point there. Gosh this is so ambiguous. But, Shashank, we don't want our program to abruptly terminate by not handling a RTE, do we?

Comment: @User2k14 That's correct. Even in the case of completely unexpected RTEs, it's usually best practice to log the exception using a logger and gracefully exit, perhaps with a friendly message to the user, letting them know that something unexpected happened and that they should send a bug report to you.

Comment: You were correct.  My instructor says: `The question asked for what is valid (which is different than what is responsible or good programming practice). The Java compiler does not enforce the handling of RuntimeExceptions (or any of its subclasses). Therefore, e was actually the correct answer.`

Comment: @User2k14 Out of curiosity, were other students confused as well by the question's wording? If so, maybe ask your teacher to ask less ambiguous questions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to handle your exception.

If you want to do something or let program keep running if exception accrue in some part of code you should use try catch and final.

If you don't want to handle the exception at that point and want to handle at some where else use throws.

So your correct answer should be d. Also C can't be your answer as "Do nothing" is not a way you should program particularly in a matter of exception.

Answer (score 0):

**The correct answer is e.**

The explanation given is:

> The question asked for what is valid (which is different than what is responsible or good programming practice). The Java compiler does not enforce the handling of RuntimeExceptions (or any of its subclasses). Therefore, e was actually the correct answer.